# Fluid simulation no longer works

Tags: fluid-simulation, baking

I'm trying to get some kind of Intro to work in which a chemical fluid turns into text. I was almost finished, but I can't get the thing with the fluid to work! A single drop should drop into an Erlenmeyer flask, which tilts over an results in text.

Basically I followed [this](https://youtu.be/YgwKPP2ZEjI) Youtube tutorial to get the fluid to work It worked fine for me once but I messed up some settings so I wanted to simulate it again. But after this first test the progress bar was always stuck after the first couple pixels. I tried everything from manually deleting the bake files to testing out an development build. The only difference I have in comparison to the tutorial is, that I'm using a single fluid object and a moving obstacle. Probably I'm missing something for me not so obvious...

Here is my project: http://www.mediafire.com/download/qp1g53tolngcgdx/RoiEXLab-intro.blend

BTW I'm using Blender 2.76b

Comment: Please add more info to your question. picture of the settings, what you have tried, etc. Just posting your blend file and saying "please fix it" is not the best way to get an answer.

Comment: Ok I added some information... I posted this yesterday right after I stopped working on the project. I was probably too desperate... ;) I you need more information please tell me...

Comment: Ok, it didn't stop, it only didn't set my system under load, so it takes a very long time!